# SQL Server query execution time is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I had to make adjustments to a query that is heavily used at my organization. Pretty much, the 'Main Query' was not picking up on shifts completed overnight. I added in the #DoubleShifts and #CombinedShifts portions. They locate all the shifts that were completed overnight. My changes work but now the query's execution time is over 3 minutes from 10 seconds, and that's not going to work.

I am simply looking for helpful hints to optimize this query for speed.

Thank you.

```
-- variables
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @dateTo DATETIME

SET @dateFrom = '03/24/2019 00:00:00'
SET @dateTo = '03/24/2019 23:59:59'

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#DoubleShifts') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DoubleShifts

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#CombinedSchedules') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #CombinedSchedules

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#callsvsAideDetailsReport') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #callsvsAideDetailsReport

-- Double Shifts
SELECT
s1.ID AS ID1,s2.ID as ID2, s1.Provider1Code, s1.FromDateTime, 
s2.ToDateTime, s1.ClientID, s1.EmpID, s1.Deleted

INTO #DoubleShifts

FROM EMR.dbo.ScheduleOfService s1, 
EMR.dbo.ScheduleOfService s2, EMR.dbo.Patients p

WHERE  
s2.FromDateTime >= @dateFrom
AND s2.ToDateTime <= @dateTo 
AND s1.ToDateTime = s2.FromDateTime
AND s1.ClientID = p.ID
AND s1.SCProg = 'H'
AND s1.ClientID = s2.ClientID
AND s1.EmpID = s2.EmpID
AND s1.Deleted = 'False'
AND s2.Deleted = 'False'
AND p.IsHospice <> 1
AND s1.Provider1Code = s2.Provider1Code

-- Schedules
SELECT ID, Provider1Code, FromDateTime, ToDateTime, ClientID, EmpID, 
       Deleted 

INTO #CombinedSchedules 

FROM EMR..ScheduleOfService s

WHERE 
FromDateTime BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo AND Deleted = 'False' 
AND s.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID1 FROM #DoubleShifts ) 
AND s.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID2 FROM #DoubleShifts )

UNION ALL

SELECT ID1 as ID, Provider1Code, FromDateTime, ToDateTime, ClientID, 
       EmpID, Deleted 

FROM #DoubleShifts

-- Main Query
SELECT
CASE WHEN p.Office <> '356' THEN ob.Office
     ELSE CASE WHEN p.TeamPatient IN ('TEAM07', 'Team09', 'Team10') THEN 
     '(01) Person1'
ELSE CASE WHEN p.TeamPatient IN ('TEAM01', 'Team02', 'Team03' ) THEN 
     '(01) Person2'
ELSE p.Team 
END END END Office,
p.CO_ORD, 
eb.id1 'Aide ID1', 
eb.[Last], 
eb.[First], 
s.Provider1Code, 
p.id1 'Member ID1', 
p.LastName, 
p.FirstName, 
s.FromDateTime,

(SELECT MAX(realizeddate) FROM EMR..compliance c
 WHERE c.EmpID = eb.id
 AND c.SubType = 'Spec1'
 AND c.RealizedDate > '03/31/2018') AS 1Date,

(SELECT MAX(realizeddate) FROM EMR..compliance c
WHERE c.EmpID = eb.id
AND c.SubType = 'Spec2'
AND c.RealizedDate > '03/31/2018') AS 2Date, 

(SELECT TOP 1 TAS_MasterId FROM db..EMR_Process
 WHERE CAST(SavedDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(s.FromDateTime AS DATE) 
 AND CAST(s.ToDateTime AS DATE)
 AND s.ClientID = EMR_ID) AS [OAR_ID]

 INTO #callsvsAideDetailsReport

FROM 
#CombinedSchedules s,
EMR..Offices_Base ob, 
EMR..Patients p, 
EMR..Employees_Base eb, 
EMR..Providers pro

WHERE 
s.EmpID = eb.ID
AND s.ClientID = p.id
AND p.Office = ob.OfficeCode
AND p.IsHospice <> 1
AND p.BillTo1 = pro.Code
AND p.BillTo1 NOT IN ('Hospice', 'CHOSPITAL,'NON-BILLABLE')
AND pro.BillTypeID NOT IN (3, 10, 20, 25)
AND s.Deleted = 'false'
AND eb.Active = 1
AND NOT p.id IN ('261110') -- nonbillable
AND NOT p.office IN ('85','95','99','357','158','153','130','111','83')
--AND s.FromDateTime BETWEEN @dateFrom and @dateTo -- End one day later 
      then the desired date range

ORDER BY 
ob.Office, p.CO_ORD, eb.[Last], eb.[first], s.Provider1Code, p.LastName, 
p.FirstName

-- TEMP TABLE
SELECT *

FROM #callsvsAideDetailsReport

ORDER BY Office, CO_ORD, [Last], [First], Provider1Code, LastName, 
         FirstName
```

There are no error messages. The run time takes over 3 minutes to complete. I would like the output to be at least under 20 seconds.

[Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SypwKzRuH)

Comment: As with any performance based question, we really need to DDL of your tables, and their relevant index, and the query plans (via Paste the Plan) (as you have multiple `SELECT... INTO` queries).

Comment: Ok, let me get that.

Comment: Not a performance changer but it is time for you to adopt ANSI-92 style joins. They have been the standard now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Do you think that adding indexes to your temp tables will help? How many records are you loading into those tables and joining against? To make use of indexes you will need to create the table the traditional way and then add the appropriate indexes. If those table are large then essentially every operation will be performed against a heap requiring a full table scans.

Comment: On a different (but related note), it's normally better to use `>= AND <` logic with dates. Instead of (what is effectively) `FromDateTime  >= '20190324' AND ToDateTime <= '2019-03-24T23:59:59'` do `FromDateTime  >= '20190324' AND ToDateTime < '20190325'`. That is completely inclusive of all times on 24 March 2019. (In your case, you would miss out anything that occur within the last second of the day, i.e. `'2019-03-24T23:59:59.003'`)

Comment: Hadn't even noticed the ANSI-89 syntax, nice spot @SeanLange .

Comment: What's the best way to get the Query Plans in here, @Larnu? @SeanLange Thanks for the feedback. As it turns out, when creating the 'Main Query' it made a lot of sense to do it the ANSI-89 way simply because I wasn't as familiar with the tables. I normally utilize ANSI-92 in my queries.

Comment: You can easily use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to upload execution plans. I would suggest going back now that you know the structure and fix those joins. They will drive you nuts in the long run and they are so prone to error because it is hard to see what is going on.

Comment: I have the plan now. What's the best way to upload it here? @Larnu

Comment: I have the plan now. What's the best way to upload it here? @SeanLange

Comment: Sean shows you how above, @MichaelJOria .

Comment: @Larnu Thank you! I have added the Query Plan in my original post.

Comment: Pretty sure Disk I/O speeds is the main factor here.. SQL Server stores temporary tables on disk if you didn't use `WITH  
        (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,  
        DURABILITY        = SCHEMA_ONLY);`..  -> [Faster temp table and table variable by using memory optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: To be honest if this was my project I would start over. The queries you have here are so overly complicated it isn't even funny. All these temp tables and such seem like they could be simplified a LOT. I would use a cte instead of temp tables. Not really a performance boost but a lot less mess to deal with. Those first two or three temp table queries can and should be a single query. The subqueries as columns should be completely rethought. Then it seems from the posted plan you need some serious indexing help on your tables. Would need to see the table definitions with indexes to really help.

Comment: @SeanLange Yup. I thought you might say that. Thanks anyway, man.

Comment: Yes totally agreed @SeanLange rewritting to use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or in combination with possibly a  [materialized view (indexable view)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) `WITH SCHEMABINDING`  as aggregation is involved are most likely the topicstarters best options..

Comment: Have you tried creating the missing indexes your query plan suggested?

Comment: @SeanLange hey man, thanks for your help again. I re-engineered the query, added the indexes, and now it flys!

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple recommendations even though I have no idea about how your data looks, but I work with a few rules of thumb and they seem to work for me most of the time.

- You have a couple NOT IN's and I would rework those to semi-join methods (EXISTS).  This will allow you to only need to do a partial matching check instead of a full comparison.

http://www.gregreda.com/2013/06/03/join-vs-exists-vs-in/

AND s.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID1 FROM #DoubleShifts ) 
AND s.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID2 FROM #DoubleShifts )

Overall, I would avoid using "IN" statements where possible, but that's just a rule of thumb and not always the case.

- You also have an order by statement near the end of your final insert into a temp table. I'd either remove the insert into a temp table or remove the order by and then return the temp table sorted.  You don't need to sort your data before inserting it into a temp table since it doesn't look like order of insert matters to you.

That's what I see for now.  Good luck!